# FIX sequence reset & status access thereafter

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

Can buyer typically reset both outgoing & incoming sequences to 1 and still query active positions related to past sequences or is this lost?

Which FIX messages & tag(s) are used to identify active positions If you suffered a data failure and lost all your records? If you only lost your activity records for the last hour, likewise, how do you query just the last hour of trade activity?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by active positions? Do you mean open orders?

Comment: open orders to me would be a pending order, which would entail a subsequent fill before being "active".  Just trying to understand how the out of sync sequence re-sync & total data loss scenarios generally play out.  You can answer in the context of either an open or filled order.

Comment: I see an open order as an order that hasn't been completely filled, so either no executions on it, or partially filled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, a buyer shouldn't typically reset any sequence numbers by himself (i.e. manually). Handling of sequence numbers should be handled by a well functioning session layer. Luckily, any decent FIX engine will handle this session layer for you, and any QuickFIX engine (QuickFIX, QuickFIX/J, QuickFIX/N, ...) implements the session layer well.

Having said that, should you choose to manually reset these sequence numbers, you can of course still "query" active positions, if you mean by that retrieve order status by way of a Status message. No information pertaining to an order will be lost as a result at the counterparty. On your end, you are supposed to keep track of order state yourself, and again, resetting sequence numbers has no effect on that (unless you would implement it as such, which would be wrong).

E.g. if an order is still open in the market, for instance it has an amount of 50 filled out of 100, you will still receive Execution Reports for any subsequent fills after a sequence reset. You can also still send Status messages to get a status overview of the order.

Now regarding data loss, it is the responsability of the buy side (or sell side) to guarantee data integrity. You should maintain your own order state in your database (or whatever counts as your data store). FIX is just the protocol to communicate, not the protocol that stores that data for you.

Apart from storing data pertaining to order state, you should have a suitable backup policy and data integrity policy in place to account for catastrophes. That means backups, full and transactional, stored at a different location than your data center etc.

AFAICT there is no FIX messaging in 4.2 to retrieve past order state from your counterparty (I'm not familiar with versions > 4.2).

Comment: So all subsequent partial order fill messages will have the same ClOrdId tag and in absolute data failures there is no FIX message that will elicit a response of all holdings of a given account?

Comment: @ElmerF (1) Yes. (2) Indeed. Also, see [definition of the FIX protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_Information_eXchange): `The Financial Information eXchange (FIX) protocol is an electronic communications protocol initiated in 1992 for international real-time **exchange of information related to the securities transactions and markets.**`. The FIX protocol has nothing to do with retrieving holdings of an account. It deals with securities transactions and markets.